# Add Spinnaker webhook to bitbucket

Tags: kubernetes, bitbucket, spinnaker

Both spinnaker and bitbucket located inside private subnet scheme. Spinnaker is deployed on kubernetes. When I try to test connection it gives this error:

```
http://spinnaker-mydomain.com:8084/webhooks/git/bitbucket
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request cannot be executed; I/O
>   reactor status: STOPPED

when I try to test connection from telnet it closes as well saying connection refused.

Wondering weather it has something to do with authentication or there is problem in bitbucket service

Answer (score 0):

If you're using BitBucket on-prem, use the url:
`http://spinnaker-mydomain.com:8084/webhooks/git/stash`